# 'I was not' vs 'I had not been'. Which one is correct?

Tags: tense

Are these sentences both correct?

> "I didn't go to the party because I **wasn't** invited."

and

> "I didn't go to the party because I **hadn't been** invited."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct: the first is probably the most idiomatic.

In the first, [invited](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/invited) is an adjective meaning **having been asked to attend**. It places the emphasis on the fact that, at the time of the party, your name wasn't on the list, so you couldn't go in.

In the second, invited is a passive-voice form of the verb invite: it emphasises the idea that, in the period leading up to the party, nobody came up to you and invited you to the party.